# Attempting to convert UnsafeMutableRawPointer back into a recognizable type

Tags: swift, unsafemutablepointer

**TL;DR** I'm attempting to convert `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` into some `UnsafePointer<T>`.

---

I've developed a Minimal Reproducible Example of my program ([Here's a snippet](https://swiftfiddle.com/nsopl47zync25p2awn7oz7yeuq))

```swift
var foo: Int = 100
var bar: String = "hello"
func unsafe(_ mutable: (UnsafeMutableRawPointer...) -> ()) {
    mutable(&foo, &bar)
}

unsafe { (mutable: UnsafeMutableRawPointer...) in
    for m in mutable {
        print(UnsafePointer<Int>(.init(m)).pointee)
    }
}
```

The goal is to print this...

```swift
100
"hello"
```

Instead, here is what was printed...

```swift
100
478560413032
```

---

Finally, if I try and replace...
`print(UnsafePointer<Int>(.init(m)).pointee)`
with...
`print(UnsafePointer<String>(.init(m)).pointee)`

I also receive a crash. (If this could be handled with `try` that would be great. But it is not a throwing method.)

---

I really wish this was possible, but unfortunately this also crashes:

```swift
print(UnsafePointer<Any>(.init(m)).pointee)
```

Comment: To be clear, are you looking to be able to go from an `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` to an arbitrary `UnsafePointer<T>` without knowing ahead of time what `T` is? (e.g. converting a `Raw` pointer to an `Int` into a non-`Raw` pointer, without somehow knowing it is an `Int`) Because this is not possible without storing that knowledge somewhere: pointers carry no additional type information with them anywhere — `UnsafePointer<T>`, once compiled, looks just like `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`, and knowledge of what `T` is isn't preserved.

Comment: If you are looking to do this arbitrarily, you will also need to pass around the `T` type you want to convert to alongside the pointer. If this isn't possible, then it might help to describe why you need to perform this conversion.

Comment: @ItaiFerber Yes that is what I want, and I guessed that was the case. I did write an example where I stored the types, and it works just fine. I'd prefer having the program guessing what T is until it finds it, though. But if it isn't possible that's alright since I have an alternative.

Comment: Yes, sadly, it's not possible for the program to "guess" what `T` is just by looking at the bits at the location of the pointer. Given your `String` example above, there's no way to tell whether `478560413032` should somehow map back to `"hello"`, or whether it should actually be the `Int` `478560413032`, or even the bit pattern `0000000000000000000000000110111101101100011011000110010101101000` corresponding to the `Double` `2.36440259538708779282881395852E-312`. You'll have to express the types alongside the pointer.

Comment: @ItaiFerber Oh that makes sense. Thank you for helping me understand!

Comment: Happy that this helped!

Comment: Can you share a version with type that works?

Comment: @MuhtasimUlfatTanmoy You'd have to write something like `for (m, type) in zip(mutable, [Int.self, String.self] as! [Any.Type])` and go from there